# How can I hide menu responsively after using jQuery toggle()?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've created a simple responsive menu - here is a slim version:
[JsFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/f0rewbm2/1/)

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleNav()">
<span class="ico"><i class="fa fa-bars hvr-icon"></i></span> Dashboard
</a><ul id="submenu">
<li>Example Menu</li>
<li>Example Menu 2</li>
<li>Example Menu 3</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
function toggleNav() {
    $("#submenu").toggle();
}
```

CSS

```
#submenu {
  display:none;
}
```

I use jQuery to toggle() the display.

If I toggle the `submenu` to display, I would like to hide it again responsively (Eg without clicking the toggle button) when the screen size increases using a media query such as:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
```

However, any CSS styles are overridden by the inline styles that toggle() writes.

Can anybody suggest a way of achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: fiddle is not having code.

Comment: fiddle link updated - thanks

Comment: Interesting solutions below.  I ended up using toggleClass in the end.  But the matchMedia function was new to me, so an upvote for both.

Comment: @Captain_Planet, I would accept the answer that you ended up using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `toggle` you can always use `toggleClass` instead. By toggling a class, that will allow you to add that class into various media queries, and style as you see fit.

```
.active{dispaly:block;}

function toggleNav() {
    $("#submenu").toggleClass("active");
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
   #submenu.active{
      display:none !important;
   }
}
```

You may or may not need the `!important`

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use the JavaScript [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) to achieve that just see the following

### Example

```
$(function(){
  var win_size = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 320px)" );
  if (win_size.matches) {
    $("#submenu").addClass();
  } else{
    $("#submenu").removeClass();
  }
});
```